# what does ことになる in this mean?

Tags: grammar

> ですから、聞く構えができている人は、より良く学べる**ことにもなります**

As far as I have learned, ことになる indicates decision, but in this context, it seems the sentence doesn't fit into the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, ことになる can mean to make or come to a decision. But it also has other meanings too. With the simplest meaning ことになる can literally mean to "become a thing" or "become the outcome / result".

So here it's roughly something like:

> ですから、聞く構えができている人は、より良く学べる**ことにもなります**
>
> Because of this (what was mentioned before), people who are able to readily listen even **have the outcome** of being better at learning.